# Objects.equals(obj1, obj2) эквивалентно obj1.equals(obj2)?

Tags: java

Равносилен ли вызов `Objects.equals(object1, object2)` вызову `object1.equals(object2)`?

Comment: нет, 1 как минимум NPE не словит. Да и сравнивает он вроде чисто по объектам, а 2 вариант перегружается.

Comment: @pavel первый вариант использует внутри второй после проверки на null. А "чисто по объектам" сравнивает оператор ==

Answer (score 6):

Смотря что вы имеете ввиду под равносильностью.
В целом, да, эти строки равносильны и обе проверяют на соответствие. 
Но, как правильно подметили в комментарии, второй случай не проверяет ссылку на null.

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
        return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```